# Setting up German language support for Pepper Robot and installing App Launcher

Tags: nao-robot, pepper

Yesterday we did a factory reset for our Pepper robot and we think it was successful. Now we wish to set up German language support in the robot. I googled some ways of doing that and found that I could set up a second language for the robot from the robot's registered account at Softbank's website which I did as you can see. [image]

But this feature did not reflect on the robot even after the reboot. Can someone please help me with this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Once the language has been installed, you need to open the settings of your robot and change the language there.

Jonas

Comment: Yes Jonas we tried that too. We went to "boot-config" application of the robot that brings up Pepper's webpage on the tablet and tried selecting the German language. But it showed no other option in the Language section other than "American English". Another problem was that I tried posting this on Aldebaran's community, but the tab kept on redirecting me to a blank page

Comment: Oh ok ! Weird, I think you should contact the customer care at support.aldebaran.com so they can investigate a little more.

Comment: I assume you also updated the robot's app packages from the downloads-tab so that it actually downloaded the german language pack and installed it? Try also ssh to Pepper and from the command line try
 `qicli call ALTextToSpeech.getAvailableLanguages`
If you don't see germany in the list, it is not available and has not been installed to the robot. If it is, you can also try to set it from command line `qicli call ALTextToSpeech._setDefaultLanguage german` or whatever the language is named in the list of available languages. That's what the robot's web page does.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, if the update does not trigger for some reason, try installing an arbitrary app from the application store, and then press the "send signal" button under 'manage' to force an update. Sometimes this seems to be needed needed. After the update in triggered and the app and language is installed, the app can be uninstalled.